# appsactivity service is not available

Tags: google-apps-script

A few weeks ago, running the script began to give the error "appsactivity service is not available".
Please Tell me what needs to be corrected in the script?
Thanks.

```
function getCloudPrintService() {
  return OAuth2.createService('print')
    .setAuthorizationBaseUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth')
    .setTokenUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')
    .setClientId(clientId)
    .setClientSecret(clientSecret)
    .setCallbackFunction('authCallback')
    .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties())
    .setScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudprint')
    .setParam('login_hint', Session.getActiveUser().getEmail())
    .setParam('access_type', 'offline')
    .setParam('approval_prompt', 'force');
}
```

Comment: `OAuth2` is not a built-in service you should mention if you declared it or if you are using a library. Also you should add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].